# Saving slider values to an array SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

```
struct MyNode : Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var weight: Double
    
    init( weight: Double ) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.weight = weight
        
    }
}

struct MyNodeView : View {
    @State var myNode : MyNode
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(String(format: "%.f", myNode.weight))%").font(.footnote)
            Slider(value: $myNode.weight, in: 0 ... 100)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Above is where I am creating the slider view so I can dynamically make a slider in a ForEach Loop. So I have a group of about 5 sliders and would like to save all of there values to an array. So [50, 60, 70, 80, 90] for each object. Is there a way of saving these values off to an array.

```
            Group {
                Text("Other defensive layers").fontWeight(.bold).foregroundColor(lightGray).padding(.vertical).padding(.leading, 30).font(.system(size: 15))
                HStack {
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(defensiveLayers, id: \.self) { layer in
                            let node = MyNode(weight: 0)
                            HStack {
                                Text(layer).font(.custom("Gill Sans", size: 12)).padding(.trailing).foregroundColor(.gray)
                                MyNodeView(myNode: node)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.padding(.horizontal, 30)
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array of `MyNode` model and use `@Binding`.

Here is the demo code.

```
struct MyNodeView : View {
    @Binding var myNode : MyNode
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(String(format: "%.f", myNode.weight))%").font(.footnote)
            Slider(value: $myNode.weight, in: 0 ... 100)
        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIDEMO: View {
    
    @State private var defensiveLayers: [MyNode] = (0..<5).map { _ -> MyNode in
        MyNode(weight: 0)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(defensiveLayers.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                MyNodeView(myNode: $defensiveLayers[index])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, so let me ask one more thing. Defensive layers is an array of objects, and it is subject to change. So my array of [MyNode] will need to be the length of defensive layers. How can I set that to the length of defensive layers count. And then how can I use that array where I am storing those values.

Comment: Why not combine both layer array with a node array model? Add MyNode object with defensiveLayer model.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing that and it works well.